# Liability of Open Ended Investment Company in Ireland

Tags: limited-liability-company, liability, ireland, liabilities

As fas as I was able to find in web, there are three main company types in Ireland:

- Limited companies
- Unlimited companies
- Funds

I need to know a liability of the shareholders of `Open Ended Investment Company`. I suppose that it should be a limited company but I can't found anything about it at all.